# Debian установка curl

Tags: php

Ребята, нашел статью где описано как обновлять на дебиане курл

```
apt-get install -y php5-curl
```

так вот у меня вопрос - а если у меня там все старое и хпх старый и все .... этой командой я не полмаю там ничего ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поломать врядли но если у вас пхп4 то curl просто не будет работать

Попробуйте 
    apt-get install -y php4-curl

Вроде должно быть.

Comment: а как узнать из консоли версию php ?

Comment: Просто php -v ))